# php loop adds extra data to database

Tags: php, laravel

I have loop to store my data and it multiple the rows.

## example

I have `3` rows with value of `test1` and I need to add this rows to become `5`
so I have `3` rows already
I add number in input field `2`
I loop this `2 number` and create new rows
previously `3` rows + `2` new rows = `5` rows in total

> but currently I am getting 9 rows.

## Code

```
foreach($request->input('barcodes') as $bb)
{
    for ($i = 0; $i < $request->input('nonuiqueAmount'); ++$i) {
        $barcode = new Barcode;
        $barcode->product_id = $product->id;
        $barcode->returned = false;
        $barcode->serial_number = $bb['serial_number'];
        $barcode->save();
    }
}
```

[image: one]

> In case you need a full code with logic [here I shared](http://collabedit.com/42c9s) it for you.

**Any idea why I get more than my desire rows?**

Comment: How does `foreach($outlets as $outlet)` come into this - it looks as though it adds the barcode for each outlet.

Comment: @NigelRen that part is absolute irrelevant to my issue and my question, that just give stored barcodes outlet id, my issue is that my data store multiple times than given number. i gave number 2 it stores 9.

Comment: @NigelRen I removed outlet part I hope your problem at least solved mine isn't.

Comment: And what do you expect? You have 3 barcodes - loop iterates 3 times and two times inner loop in each iteration. Already 6.

Comment: @u_mulder I expect to have `= 5 rows in total` (i have 3, make 2 more = 5)

Comment: *I hope your problem at least solved* - I personally don't have a problem with it at all!

Comment: Iterate over `$request->input('nonuiqueAmount')` outisde of `foreach`?

Comment: @u_mulder that would work probably but then how do I access `$bb['serial_number']`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Solved

Thanks to `u_mulder` suggestion here is how I solved my issue

```
    foreach($request->input('barcodes') as $bb)
    {
        $bbb = $bb['serial_number']; // added to get single serial number
    }
    for ($i = 0; $i < $request->input('nonuiqueAmount'); ++$i) {
        $barcode = new Barcode;
        $barcode->product_id = $product->id;
        $barcode->returned = false;
        $barcode->serial_number = $bbb; // changed
        if($barcode->save()) {
            $user = Auth::user();
            $outlets = $user->outlets;
            foreach($outlets as $outlet) {
                DB::table('outlet_products')->insert([
                    'outlet_id' => $outlet->id,
                    'barcode_id' => $barcode->id,
                    'created_at' => now(),
                    'updated_at' => now(),
                ]);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: But all extra records will have last `serial_number`? It it okay?